# What is the abstract name for Drive, Directory and file?

Tags: naming

I want to give nice name to my function while returns drive, directory and file. Can you please suggest a good abstract name for this trio?

This is the function.

```
  static IEnumerable<string> GetDriveDirectoriesAndFile(string path)
  {
     if (path.Contains('/'))
     {
        path = path.Replace('/', '\\');
     }
     if (path.Contains('\\'))
     {
        return path.Split('\\');
     }
     return null;
  }
```

Thanks,
Omkar

Comment: will it return the whole thing at once, like on windows "C:/programs/something"? This would mostly be called a file_path.

Comment: It takes path and return IEnumerable<string> which contains C:,programs,something.txt like that.. thanks

Comment: How about "FileSystemObjects"? It's the only term I can think of that covers them all.

Comment: AbstractNamingPathVisitorAdapterContext - sorry, I had to poke fun at the over-sophisticated names that come from overuse of design patterns.  Path element, path part or path component are all fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it looks like you are using .NET, if possible I would suggest using the terminology in the [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx) class:

- **Root** (Drive letter such as C:\ or UNC such as \server\share)
- **Directory Name**
- **File Name**

Also, if possible, I would suggest using the Path, FileInfo, and DirectoryInfo classes when working with file system paths, rather then attempting to do the splitting, combining, and parsing on your own.

Comment: Bingo... Exactly what looking for... 
In control systems such solutions are called feed Forward systems....

Answer (score 6):

How about calling your method `GetPathComponents(string path)`?

Comment: +1 - Components is better than my suggestion

Comment: File itself cannot be a component of path. These all can be categorized under file system objects... FileSystemObject is closer to the correct nam right now for me..

Comment: @Omkar panhalkar: I disagree (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) article). However, use whatever you prefer. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to suggest "FileSystemObjects", Or if you want to shorten it: "FSObjects", or "FSOs", or some variant of that.

Comment: Thanks frustrated person...LOL... Thanks a lot.. I decided to go with GetFileSystemObjects... :)